# How does 1:30 sound?

Tags: phrasing

Someone overheard me say **"How does 1:30 sound?"** and suggested that the preferred way to phrase this question (i.e., when scheduling a meeting) would be to ask **"How does 1:30 work?"** or **"Does 1:30 sound good?"**

In my mind, all three phrasings sound natural, and I've always used the "How does 1:30 sound?" construction. Is anything out of place here?

Comment: I think it is ok : to sound: to present a particular impression: That argument sounds reasonable.

Comment: All three forms are idiomatic in U.S. English, and I don't see any reason to consider one better or worse than the others. The likeliest explanation here is that the person who saw fit to correct you has a narrower appreciation of the idiomatic possibilities than you do—and a narrow perspective is undoubtedly a point of strength when it comes to telling other people that they are doing something the wrong way.

Comment: I'm tempted to change the title to "How does 'How does 1:30 sound?' sound?" :-)

Comment: All 'sound' perfectly idiomatic and usable to me.

Comment: "Tick ... tick ... tick ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with "How does 1:30 sound?"  It simply invites a response of "Sounds good" as an affirmative, and any number of possibilities as a negative.  The alternative offered, "Does 1:30 sound good?", just rephrases the question to invite a straight yes-or-no answer.

(There is no difference that I can discern between "How does 1:30 sound?" and "How does 1:30 work?".)

Answer (score 2):

I think that if they had wanted to "correct" you, they should have suggested that you say "How does 1:30 sound TO YOU?" or "Does 1:30 sound good for you?". Or even, "Is 1:30 good for you?" But that's just quibbling, really; their suggestion is every bit as valid as what you originally said, IMHO.